# Mouse cursor jumping and clicking erratically

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse

I have a Windows 10 installation, that up to now worked fine. Now the mouse cursor suddenly started to act up. It now jumps around the screen (like, actually jumping, not moving fast) and left- and right-clicks randomly. This happens about 3-5 times per second. I can still move the cursor and click, but whatever I am doing is interrupted by the mouse jumping and clicking on it's own.

This also makes it very difficult to debug the problem, since I cannot even do anything with the keyboard, since the mouse clicks take away the focus of whatever I am trying to do.

Other than some Windows update there has been no change on the PC since it worked. No new software was installed and I am pretty certain, it is not malware that causes that. I tried using Windows System Restore to go to a point before the update, but that changes nothing.

I cannot get into Safe Mode, since for some reason F8 or Shift+F8 don't seem to work and due to the mouse clicking randomly I cannot get into Safe Mode from Windows.

The problem even persists if I disconnect the mouse from the USB port and in the recovery settings.

The device is a HP desktop (can't give much more information since I cannot access it), without a touchpad or touchscreen.

I think it is a Windows problem, since the problem does not show up on a live Linux booted over USB.

Any ideas on how I could solve that problem?

Also, is there any way to disable the mouse cursor completely using some kind of keyboard shortcut, so that I can at least use the keyboard to navigate?

Comment: What about if you disconnect the mouse and the keyboard (and any other external USB devices)?

Comment: I disconnected all USB, serial, PS/2 and Ethernet connections and the behaviour still exists. I booted into the Windows 10 installation ISO and even there the problem exists. It does not happen on every boot. On about one out of five reboots the problem does not show up, until I reboot.

Comment: I haven't seen the Windows 10 ISO, but does it load Windows (I imagine not since installation is it's purpose)? If not, it is strange that Linux ISO is OK but not Windows ISO. Are both USB or CD/DVD? And how about the system ROM boot menu?

Comment: Also, have you run a decent memory check, such a [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)? If you can make the boot CD it will autorun on boot. I wonder because the drivers for each OS would load at different memory locations.